# How to add Canvas to JFrame from another class?

Tags: java, awt

I know I can just write the Canvas inside the JFrame class, but what if I want a separate canvas class?

I'm new to java programming. Sorry if it's just a simple problem.

```
public class TheFrame {

    private JFrame theframe;
    private String title = "Test";
    private int width = 1024;
    private int height = 576;

    public TheFrame(){
        theframe = new JFrame(title);
        theframe.setSize(width, height);
        theframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        theframe.setVisible(true);

        //call the canvas
        TheCanvas thecanvas = new TheCanvas(width, height);

        //!
        theframe.add(thecanvas);
    }    
}
```

```
public class TheCanvas {

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Canvas thecanvas;
    public TheCanvas(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        thecanvas = new Canvas();
        thecanvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        thecanvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        thecanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        //!
        theframe.add(thecanvas);
    }
}
```

Separate method example: This works, with a "private canvas thecanvas" object.

```
    public TheFrame(){
        theframe = new JFrame(title);
        theframe.setSize(width, height);
        theframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        theframe.setVisible(true);

        //call the canvass
        TheCanvasX(width, height);

        theframe.add(thecanvas);
    }    

    public void TheCanvasX(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        thecanvas = new Canvas();
        thecanvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        thecanvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        thecanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }
```

Canvas not separated example: This works. The most common way to add canvas.

```
    public TheFrame(){
        theframe = new JFrame(title);
        theframe.setSize(width, height);
        theframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        theframe.setVisible(true);

        thecanvas = new Canvas();
        thecanvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        thecanvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        thecanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));        

        theframe.add(thecanvas);
    }
```

Comment: I would recommending not passing the size to `TheCanvas` and instead, let `TheCanvas` define the size it wants to be, his way you can use `Frame#pack` to pack the window around the contents and a truer representation of the available content area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I've Added a getter method.

```
public class TheFrame {

    private JFrame theframe;
    private String title = "Test";
    private int width = 1024;
    private int height = 576;

    public TheFrame(){
        theframe = new JFrame(title);
        theframe.setSize(width, height);
        theframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        theframe.setVisible(true);

        //call the canvas
        TheCanvas thecanvas = new TheCanvas(width, height);

        //!
        theframe.add(thecanvas.getTheCanvas());
    }    
}
```

```
public class TheCanvas {

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Canvas thecanvas;
    public TheCanvas(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        thecanvas = new Canvas();
        thecanvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        thecanvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        thecanvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    public Canvas getTheCanvas(){
        return thecanvas;
    }
}
```